# Uitableview Gets weird for iOS7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Attaching screenshot for better understanding. 
In iOS 8.3 it look as expected [image]

and in iOs7.1 it remove space from left and right(I don't know whether it remove UITableviwcell issue for TableView issue ).

[image]

I search on web but not able to find solution for it.
Please guys any suggestion?

Comment: Add some code. Only screenshots can not be understood.

Comment: Check `layoutMargins` property of UIView. It is not available prior to iOS 8. I think that is your problem.

Comment: @pe60t0 Okay you mean to say I have to set layoumargin progrmatically for prior ios8?

Comment: @Ashish No extra code,as it is running fine in iOS8 and above but ios 7 it has this issue. I use custom Cell which have UIView and content inside it but i give autolayout constrains which are trailing to superview and leading to superview but it actually have space of 8px. So not sure why it says superview to 8px in Xcode 6.

Comment: Yeah thats the thing - if you have designed your layout using the layoutMargins, you need to design it again to compensate for this. So just use left spacing equal to whatever you have used in iOS 8.

Comment: Can you add some code here ? so anyone can see. what you have done.

Comment: Remove all margin constraints, and use the `normal` constraints to match them. Note the position of the tableView within its superview as well as the tableViewCells.

Answer (score 0):

1. Increase the x co-ordinate of the image cell as seen in screenshot.
2. Select tableView in storyboard, select `separator insets` option to `custom` and reduce "Left" from 15 to 0.
3. Add the following lines of code in cellForRowAtIndexPath

   if ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue >= 8.0f)

   {

   ```
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = NO;
   ```

   }